# How to list the types of a influxdb measurement fields?

Tags: influxdb

I have an influxdb with a `measurement` named `http_reqs`. This measurement has several fields which I can 'list' as follows (I see 11 fields):

```
SELECT * FROM http_reqs LIMIT 1;
```

Here the first line of the output is as follows:

```
time error error_code method name proto scenario status tls_version type url value
```

I assume to have 11 fields in that 'measurement' `http_reqs`:

```
time 
error
error_code 
method 
name 
proto 
scenario 
status 
tls_version 
type 
url 
value
```

I want to know the 'type' of these fields.

For example:

I the field `status` a string? Or is the field `status` an integer? Or is the field `status` a float? Or is the field `status` a boolean?

I hope my question if a bit more clear now.

I found [this documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-schema/) and I can run

```
SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM http_reqs;
```

but it seems to list only 2 fields! The output is:

```
name: http_reqs
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
url      string
value    float
```

Yes that is what I want for all of the fields! I can see, that the field `url` has type `string`, and I can see that the field `value` is of type `float`.

But 9 of the above listed fields seem to be missing. I see only two fields (`url` and `value`). I do not see the type of the field `status`, for example. I want to know the type of the field `status`.

I also can do the following query:

```
SHOW TAG KEYS FROM http_reqs
```

which gives this output:

```
name: http_reqs
tagKey
------
error
error_code
method
name
proto
scenario
status
tls_version
type
```

Interestingly, this query lists all of the 9 'missing' fields (or tags, or keys, or whatever these things are). But this output does not tell me what type the element `status` is, for example. I want to know the type of the element `status`.

How can I see the types of each of the 11 elements of the 'measurement' `http_reqs`?

Answer (score -1):

Your term `fields` is very likely `InfluxDB fields` + `InfluxDB tags` in your case:

Inspect InfluxDB fields:

```
SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM http_reqs
```

Inspect InfluxDB tags:

```
SHOW TAG KEYS FROM http_reqs
```